# How can I prevent events being fired on the Winform when I click on a WPF popup?

Tags: wpf, events, popup, wpf-controls

I have a wondows form which contains a WPF control as well. When I click on the control it brings up a WPF popup control with a listbox. The goal is, when I select an item on the listbox, the windows form will be repopulated accordingly and the popup should get closed. The current implementation with SelectionChanged on the listbox works fine.

Here is the problem. The popup is big and covers some portion of the winform which contains some links. Now, when I select an item on the listbox, the popup closes after doing necessary actions, but if there is a link just below the popup (on the winform) that is under the cursor (when you selected the item on the listbox), that link is also taking the click event.

Is there any way to prevent the links getting clicked when I click on the popup? I have to close the popup though.

Comment: Just to add: In the SelectionChanged event handler I close the popup. If I put a sleep of 100 ms before closing the popup (make it stay for 100ms after completing everything in SelectionChanged), the links on the winform do not get the click event. But, I guess that is not a good solution as sometimes it works for 10 ms and occasionally it does not for even 100ms. basically, I do not know how long to wait before closing the popup. Need a definitive point at which I can safely close the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.

SelectionChanged gets executed when we press the mouse key down and before we lift it.(Mouse key up). The popup gets closed in SelectionChanged before we lift the Mouse key. So, when we leave the mouse key, the keyUp event actually gets fired for a link on the Winform as the popup has been closed by now.

I moved the logic from SelectionChanged to PreviewMouseUp and the popup stays till I leave the mouse  key and therefore the links on the Winform do not get the event. Of course, I check whether the selection has been changed or not.